# Showing combo box when a specific selection occurs

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am coding a bookshop in Java and have a problem with when a new book is ordered I want the user to select whether it is a ebook or paper book. If it is an ebook I want another combo box to show on the page with called `cboFormat`. I have some code but it doesn't seem to work.

This is in the constructor.

```
if("Ebook".equals(cboBookType.getSelectedItem()))
    {
        cboFormat.enable();
    }
     else 
     {
     cboFormat.disable();
     }
```

Why doesn't this work? I have also previously set the format input to disabled.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - this is Swing based, right?  Feel free to add more than one tag to questions, they are 'free'..

Comment: verify the value of `cboBookType.getSelectedItem()`. Write it to a variable and check the value.

Answer (score 1):

This could be that you do not have a actionlistener on your combo box ? As Andrew suggested, there could be more reasons why your block does not work. If you pasted more code it would be easier to determine what the problem is. If however you are missing action listener on your combo box, code below.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox cboBookType = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String bookType= (String)cboBookType.getSelectedItem();
            //and paste your ifs here
            if("Ebook".equals.....){
              ...
            }
        ... rest of code
    }
```

And if you don't know what action listener is, its basically interface used by other classes to listen for an action event. i.e. user clicking button, or user selecting checkbox etc.

Comment: It could be due to a lot of things.  Note that any answer for which the only sentence is a question, is not a good candidate as an answer at all.

Comment: *"If you pasted more code.."*  Ugh.  So we can look forward to dribs and drabs of uncompilable code snippets that aren't relevant.  The OP should post one **SSCCE** like I advised over 40 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use enable and disable try this and dont put it in the constructor because then it wont get updated you have to make a new event like itemchanged or itemstatechanged i dont know it exactly

```
   if("Ebook".equals(cboBookType.getSelectedItem()))
    {
        cboFormat.setvisible(true);
    }
     else 
     {
     cboFormat.setvisible(false);
     }
```